# My chart data with 2 condition (without date input and with date input) not showing any result

Tags: javascript, php, json, mysql-workbench

Currently I have some problem with my code. There are 2 pages.

I try to pull data from database in the read file and post it to index to display the data in the form of chart. I also create 2 types of input where the user can filter the data by range of date and time. The problem is my index does not show any kind of result(chart) of the data.Please help.

1. index.php

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(data){
           $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
               format:'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'
           });

           $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
               format:'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'
           });

           fetch_data('no');

           function fetch_data(is_date_search,datetimepicker='',datetimepicker1=''){
               $.ajax({
                   url:"read.php",
                   async: false,
                   dataType: 'json',
                   type:"post",
                   data:{
                       is_date_search:is_date_search,datetimepicker:datetimepicker,datetimepicker1:datetimepicker1
                   },

                   success: function(data){
                       console.log(data);
                       var grade = [];
                       var percentage = [];

                       for (var i in data){
                           grade.push(data[i].grade);
                           percentage.push(data[i].percentage);
                       }

                       var chartdata = {
                           labels: grade,
                           datasets : [
                               {
                                   label: 'Yield report',                      
                                   backgroundColor: [
                                       'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                       'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                       'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                       'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                       'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                       'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                                       'rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.2)',
                                       'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)',
                                       'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)'
                                   ],
                                   borderColor: [
                                       'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                       'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                       'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                       'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                       'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                       'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                                       'rgba(0, 128, 128, 1)',
                                       'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
                                       'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)'
                                   ],
                                   hoverBackgroundColor: [
                                       'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                       'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                       'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                       'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                       'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                       'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                                       'rgba(0, 128, 128, 1)',
                                       'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
                                       'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)'
                                   ],
                                   hoverBorderColor: [
                                       'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                       'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                       'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                       'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                       'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                       'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                                       'rgba(0, 128, 128, 1)',
                                       'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
                                       'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)'
                                   ],
                                   data: percentage
                               }
                           ]
                       };

                       var ctx = $("#myChart");

                       var barGraph = new Chart(ctx,{
                           type: 'bar',
                           data: chartdata         
                       });
                   },
                   error: function(){}
               });     
           }

           $('#search').click(function(){
               var start_date = $('.datetimepicker').val();
               var end_date = $('.datetimepicker1').val();

               if(start_date !='' && end_date !='')
               {
                   fetch_data('yes', start_date, end_date);
               }
               else
               {
                   alert("Both Date is Required");
               }

           });


       });
   </script>
   ```
2. read.php

   ```
   $columns = array( 
       // datatable column index  => database column name
       0 => 'grade', 
       1 => 'quantity', 
       2 => 'percentage'
   );


   $sql = "SELECT category.grade as grade,gradesum.quantity as quantity, gradesum.percentage as percentage FROM";

   if($_POST["is_date_search"]!="yes")
   {

       $currentdate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

       $datenow = $currentdate->format('Y-m-d');
       $timenow = $currentdate->format('H:i:s');

       $startdate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', time())));

       $dateyesterday = $startdate->format('Y-m-d');
       $timeyesterday = $startdate->format('H:i:s');

       if($timenow >= '07:30:00')
       {
           $timenow1 = '07:30:00';
           $finaldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$datenow $timenow1"));

       }
       else if($timenow < '07:30:00')
       {
           $timenow2 = '07:30:00';
           $finaldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$datenow $timenow2"));          
       }


       if($timeyesterday >= '07:30:00')
       {
           $timeyesterday1 = '07:30:00';
           $finaldate1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$dateyesterday $timeyesterday1"));         
       }
       else if($timeyesterday < '07:30:00')
       {
           $timeyesterday2 = '07:30:00';
           $finaldate1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$dateyesterday $timeyesterday2"));         
       }

       $sql .="
               (
                   (
                       SELECT grade FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                       WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                               AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'
                               OR status IS NULL)
                       AND grade != 'RR'
                       GROUP BY grade
                   )category

                   LEFT JOIN        

                   (        
                       SELECT grade,sum(qtty) as quantity,
                       CAST((sum(qtty)/(
                                   SELECT sum(qtty) FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                                   WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                                   AND (
                                           ((1065_move_in_time >= '".$finaldate1."'AND 1065_move_in_time < '".$finaldate."')AND grade !='A1')
                                           OR 
                                           ((1060_move_out_time >= '".$finaldate1."'AND 1060_move_out_time < '".$finaldate."')AND grade = 'A1')
                                       )
                                   AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'OR status IS NULL)
                                   )* 100)as decimal (10,2)) as percentage
                       FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                       WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                               AND
                               (
                                   ((1065_move_in_time >= '".$finaldate1."' AND 1065_move_in_time < '".$finaldate."')AND grade != 'A1')
                                   OR 
                                   ((1060_move_out_time >= '".$finaldate1."' AND 1060_move_out_time < '".$finaldate."') AND grade = 'A1')
                               )
                               AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'
                               OR status IS NULL)
                       GROUP BY grade
                   )gradesum on category.grade = gradesum.grade
               )       
       ";
   }

   if($_POST["is_date_search"]=="yes")
   {
       $sql .= "               
       (
           (
               SELECT grade FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
               WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                       AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'
                       OR status IS NULL)
               AND grade != 'RR'
               GROUP BY grade
           )category

               LEFT JOIN        

               (        
                   SELECT grade,sum(qtty) as quantity,
                   CAST((sum(qtty)/(
                               SELECT sum(qtty) FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                               WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                               AND (
                                       ((1065_move_in_time >= '".$POST_['datetimepicker']."'AND 1065_move_in_time < '".$POST_['datetimepicker1']."')AND grade !='A1')
                                       OR 
                                       ((1060_move_out_time >= '".$POST_['datetimepicker']."'AND 1060_move_out_time < '".$POST_['datetimepicker1']."')AND grade = 'A1')
                                   )
                               AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'OR status IS NULL)
                               )* 100)as decimal (10,2)) as percentage
                   FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                   WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                           AND
                           (
                               ((1065_move_in_time >= '".$POST_['datetimepicker']."' AND 1065_move_in_time < '".$POST_['datetimepicker1']."')AND grade != 'A1')
                               OR 
                               ((1060_move_out_time >= '".$POST_['datetimepicker']."' AND 1060_move_out_time < '".$POST_['datetimepicker1']."') AND grade = 'A1')
                           )
                           AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'
                           OR status IS NULL)
                   GROUP BY grade
               )gradesum on category.grade = gradesum.grade
           )
       ";

   }


   $query=mysqli_query($cell2, $sql) or die("-");
   $totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
   //echo $totalData;
   $totalFiltered = $totalData;  

   $sqls = "SELECT category.grade as grade,gradesum.quantity as quantity, gradesum.percentage as percentage FROM";

           if($_POST["is_date_search"]!="yes")
           {

       $currentdate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

   $datenow = $currentdate->format('Y-m-d');
   $timenow = $currentdate->format('H:i:s');

   $startdate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', time())));

   $dateyesterday = $startdate->format('Y-m-d');
   $timeyesterday = $startdate->format('H:i:s');

   if($timenow >= '07:30:00')
   {
       $timenow1 = '07:30:00';
       $finaldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$datenow $timenow1"));

   }
   else if($timenow < '07:30:00')
   {
       $timenow2 = '07:30:00';
       $finaldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$datenow $timenow2"));          
   }


   if($timeyesterday >= '07:30:00')
   {
       $timeyesterday1 = '07:30:00';
       $finaldate1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$dateyesterday $timeyesterday1"));         
   }
   else if($timeyesterday < '07:30:00')
   {
       $timeyesterday2 = '07:30:00';
       $finaldate1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$dateyesterday $timeyesterday2"));         
   }

   $sqls .="
           (
               (
                   SELECT grade FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                   WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                           AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'
                           OR status IS NULL)
                   AND grade != 'RR'
                   GROUP BY grade
               )category

               LEFT JOIN        

               (        
                   SELECT grade,sum(qtty) as quantity,
                   CAST((sum(qtty)/(
                               SELECT sum(qtty) FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                               WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                               AND (
                                       ((1065_move_in_time >= '".$finaldate1."'AND 1065_move_in_time < '".$finaldate."')AND grade !='A1')
                                       OR 
                                       ((1060_move_out_time >= '".$finaldate1."'AND 1060_move_out_time < '".$finaldate."')AND grade = 'A1')
                                   )
                               AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'OR status IS NULL)
                               )* 100)as decimal (10,2)) as percentage
                   FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                   WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                           AND
                           (
                               ((1065_move_in_time >= '".$finaldate1."' AND 1065_move_in_time < '".$finaldate."')AND grade != 'A1')
                               OR 
                               ((1060_move_out_time >= '".$finaldate1."' AND 1060_move_out_time < '".$finaldate."') AND grade = 'A1')
                           )
                           AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'
                           OR status IS NULL)
                   GROUP BY grade
               )gradesum on category.grade = gradesum.grade
           )       
   ";


   }


   if($_POST["is_date_search"]=="yes")
   {
   $sqls .= "              
   (
               (
                   SELECT grade FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                   WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                           AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'
                           OR status IS NULL)
                   AND grade != 'RR'
                   GROUP BY grade
               )category

               LEFT JOIN        

               (        
                   SELECT grade,sum(qtty) as quantity,
                   CAST((sum(qtty)/(
                               SELECT sum(qtty) FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                               WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                               AND (
                                       ((1065_move_in_time >= '".$POST_['datetimepicker']."'AND 1065_move_in_time < '".$POST_['datetimepicker1']."')AND grade !='A1')
                                       OR 
                                       ((1060_move_out_time >= '".$POST_['datetimepicker']."'AND 1060_move_out_time < '".$POST_['datetimepicker1']."')AND grade = 'A1')
                                   )
                               AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'OR status IS NULL)
                               )* 100)as decimal (10,2)) as percentage
                   FROM mcs_cell2.mcs_stack_id_gen_combined
                   WHERE wo LIKE '%szb%'
                           AND
                           (
                               ((1065_move_in_time >= '".$POST_['datetimepicker']."' AND 1065_move_in_time < '".$POST_['datetimepicker1']."')AND grade != 'A1')
                               OR 
                               ((1060_move_out_time >= '".$POST_['datetimepicker']."' AND 1060_move_out_time < '".$POST_['datetimepicker1']."') AND grade = 'A1')
                           )
                           AND (status NOT LIKE 'terminate%'
                           OR status IS NULL)
                   GROUP BY grade
               )gradesum on category.grade = gradesum.grade
           )
   ";

   }



   $query=mysqli_query($cell2, $sqls) or die("read.php: get events1");
   $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result.



   $sqls.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
   $query=mysqli_query($cell2, $sqls) or die("read.php: get events2");

   $data = array();
   while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
   $nestedData=array();

   $nestedData[] = $row["grade"];
   $nestedData[] = $row["quantity"];
   $nestedData[] = $row["percentage"];



   $data[] = $nestedData;
   }



   $json_data = array(
           "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),  
           "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  
           "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), totalFiltered = totalData
           "data"            => $data   

   echo json_encode($json_data);
   ```